no puedo hacer que entre una imagen dentro del contenedor con css
¿Cómo están? soy nueva y estuve tratando de hacer una "calesita" con el lenguaje de programación h t m l  y  c s s . El problema que estoy teniendo es que no puedo hacer que las imágenes entren dentro de la etiqueta contenedora, hice de todo: escribí la anchura 100%, la altura lo mismo en el contenedor puse o b j e c t - f i t : f i l l ; y tampoco me puso las imágenes dentro del contenedor, miren :
 .carrousel {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0%;
    border: solid black;

    margin: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    padding: none;
    display: inline-block;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 1000px;

}

.carrousel-image {
    width: 50%; 
    height: 100%; 
    padding: none;
    object-fit: cover;
}


El código y los mensajes de error siempre como texto, con formato. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Hola Cande, bienvenida, tanto el código como los mensajes de error, deben estar en formato texto, no en imágenes, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, de esa forma lograrás que sea mejor recibida y evitarás recibir votos negativos. .

En la clase carrousel-image debes  colocar un width de 100% para que la imagen ocupe todo el ancho del contenedor y un height en auto para que ajueste automático  la altura y mantener la proporción.
Asi quedaria el codigo:
 .carrousel {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 100%;
    border: solid black;
}

.carrousel-image {
    width: 100%; 
    height: auto; 
    object-fit: cover;
}


Hola Alberto ¿Cómo está? no estoy pudiendo hacer que las imágenes estén del mismo tamaño una al lado de la otra, tienen tamaños distintos, solo una tiene borde, etc. ya hice todos tus pasos del ejemplo

Por favor muéstrame el código HTML Completo y el CSS completo, para mostrarlo en tipo  texto/código te aconsejo que edites Tú pregunta y copies y pegues el código para ello lo debes encerras con tres literales (acentos invertidos)  seguido de la palabra HTML y luego lo cierras con tres literales solamente igual lo vas a hacer cuando coloques el codigo CSS y asi podemos ver el codigo en texto con formato, de igual forma edite tu pregunta para que veas como se hace.
